# Factorization of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that has one integer parameter (let's call it ), which returns as a result a vector consisting of all prime factors of the number , where each factor appears as many times how many times it appears in the factorization of numbers into prime factors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

bool is_prime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

std::vector<int> PrimeFactors(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> a, b, temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (is_prime(i))
            temp.push_back(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < temp.size(); k++)
            {
                if (temp[i] * temp[j] == n)
                {
                    b.push_back(temp[i]);
                    b.push_back(temp[j]);
                    return b;
                }
                if (temp[i] * temp[j] * temp[k] == n)
                {
                    b.push_back(temp[i]);
                    b.push_back(temp[j]);
                    b.push_back(temp[k]);
                    return b;
                }
            }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    for (int i : PrimeFactors(n))
        std::cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Storing number exactly the time it appears in factorization makes this tough a little bit. Could you give an idea for algorithm?

Comment: `std::vector<int>PrimeFactors` -- This function has a return path that does not return anything.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: You could speed this up tremendously by having a hardcoded table of primes in your `is_prime` function.  Let's say the first 200 primes.  Otherwise you are calling `is_prime` a **lot** of times.

Comment: If you keep your `is_prime` function, your loop should start at 3 and increment by 2.  All primes, except for 2, are odd.  This removes 50% of the function's execution time.

Comment: Also, in your `is_prime` function use `i * i < n` as your conditional expression.  The `sqrt` function is slower than multiplication and may produce rounding errors because it's a floating point function.

Comment: For an algorithm, search the internet for "C++ Greatest Common Divisor GCD"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the % operator to find numbers that divide n evenly. Each time you find a factor, divide n by that factor as long as it continues to divide evenly.

```
std::vector<int> PrimeFactors(int n) {
    std::vector<int> r;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i += 1 + (i > 2)) {
        while ((n % i) == 0) {
            r.push_back(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n != 1)
        r.push_back(n);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: could you explain me why this condition `if (n != 1)` ?

Comment: I changed the loop to end at i * i <= n, which is a lot quicker, but will often end with n itself being a large prime. For example, n = 99 will find 3 twice leaving n = 11, then increase i to 4 and exit the loop because 4 * 4 > 11, but 11 should be added to the list of factors. n is always prime at that point because it has been divided by every prime < sqrt(n). On the other hand, e.g n = 8 would find 3 twos, leaving n = 1 which shouldn't be in the list of prime factors.

Comment: thanks, this confuses me a little bit https://godbolt.org/z/W53q4Tn9e if n=30, at the end of loop n will be equal to 5, how is then vector consisting of only one number (which is 5) represented as 2, 3, 5 ?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WMGvT6csj Actually, I'm wrong I think, the i * i <= n case makes sure n never gets to 1. You'd need that if you changed it to while((n % i) == 0) { r.push_back(i); n /= i; } to save on is_prime calls.

Comment: You shouldn't need `is_prime`: whenever `i` divides `n`, it's the smallest divisor of the current `n` (because we counted up to get there), and the smallest divisor can only be a prime.

Comment: Very good point